# How can I autocomplete override methods with multiple parameters in xCode?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete

I've found that if I type `- something` I'll get autocomplete for overriding an instance method, which looks like this

[image]

The problem is that especially in this case there are a lot of methods and the only way to find one is manually. The only way to narrow this down is to specify the return type, like

`- (NSInteger)table`

which results in the following

[image]

but this requires you to know the exact return type (which isn't autocompleted).

What I'm looking for is something like AppCode's Override Method which allows you to quickly search by the whole method name

[image]

Is there something like this available possible in xCode? Or even with a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin - I personally haven't tried it but seems to be just what you're looking for.